# avoid eval in this module

Tags: javascript, eval

I have this module pattern that stores a bunch of vars. I want to create a single function that can return any given var (the real module has real functions- this is just a striped down version).

```
var myObject = (function() {
  var _savings = '100',
      _year = new Date().getFullYear(),
      _phone = '1-800-555-1234';

return {
  getMe: function(param) {
    return eval(param);
}
```

an example useage would be `myObject.getMe('phone');` would poop out "1-800-555-1234"

I want to avoid the use of eval(), since its so evil.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript, `object.field` is equivalent to `object["field"]`.

Now, the problem here is that you've created some private variables that don't belong to an object, so accessing them will be tricky.

An alternative approach would be this:

```
var myObject = (function() {
  var _privates = {
    savings: '100',
    year: new Date().getFullYear(),
    phone: '1-800-555-1234'
  };

return {
  getMe: function(param) {
    return _privates[param];
  }
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this the object-oriented way, you could first create a prototype definition with the members *_savings*, *_year*, *_phone*.  Add *getMe* to the prototype:

```
var myClass = function() {
    this._savings = '100',
    this._year = new Date().getFullYear(),
    this._phone = '1-800-555-1234';

    myClass.prototype.getMe = function(param) {
       return this[param]; 
    }
}
```

Then instantiate the object and run the method:

```
var myObject = new myClass();
console.log(myObject.getMe("_savings"));
  // "100"
```

---

*Edited original answer* (as Dancrumb points out, this does not work; they are private members, so inside the function *getMe* there is no way to see them).

<s>Use bracket notation:</s>

return this[param];

Comment: Would only work for public fields, not private ones like these

Comment: @Dancrumb thanks, you're right of course.  I rewrote my answer.

Comment: sorry to keep picking, but now you've made these fields public, which means that users can modify them. The OP's technique makes them readonly

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var myObject = (function() {
    var data = {
        savings: '100',
        year: new Date().getFullYear(),
        phone: '1-800-555-1234'
    };
    return {
        getMe: function(param) {return data[param];}
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = {
    phone: '1-800-555-1234',
    year: new Date().getFullYear(),
    savings: 100,
    getMe: function(param) {
        return this[param];
    }
};
alert(myObject.getMe('phone'));
```